# Селектор - найти id элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите найти значение атрибута.

Есть блок с `id="block13"`
Есть `var fix = 12`

```
$("#block"+fix).attr();
```

Число переменной fix менять нельзя.
Может есть функция которая находит ближайший id, по значению.

Comment: Ближайший в какую сторону?

Comment: _Может есть функция которая находит ближайший id, по значению._ - такой функции нет.

Answer (score 2):

Такое себе, но работает (jQuery):

```js
let fix = 12, 
  collection = $('div[id^="block"]');

function findClosestBlock (inFix, seeckDirection = 1, collection) {
  if (collection) { 
    if (seeckDirection) { // если 1, происходит поиск от меньших id к большим
      collection.each(function (i, el) {
        if (el.id.match(/\d+/)[0] > fix) {
          console.log(el.id);
          return false;
        }
      })
    } else { // если 0, переворачивает массив элементов и щем от большего id к меньшему
      $(collection.get().reverse()).each(function (i, el) {
        if (el.id.match(/\d+/)[0] < fix) {
          console.log(el.id);
          return false;
        }
      })
    }
  }
}

findClosestBlock(fix, 1, collection); // второй аргумент - направление поиска
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block8"></div>
<div id="block9"></div>
<div id="block10"></div>
<div id="block11"></div>
<div id="block12"></div>
<div id="block13"></div>
```

Comment: а можно комментарии к коду чтобы понять как оно работает.?я блок else не понимаю

Comment: добавил в ответ

Comment: благодарю ......

Answer (score 1):

```js
/**
 * Ищет элементы с ближайшим номером в id
 * @param {string} idBase - начало id (до числа)
 * @param {number} n - число, "вокруг" которого искать
 * @param {boolean} withN - включать ли в результат элемент с указанным n
 * @return {HTMLElement[]} сортированный массив элементов, или null при ошибке параметров
 */
function findByNum(idBase, n, withN) {
  idBase = idBase.replace('#', '').trim().split(/\s+/)[0]; 
  if (!isFinite(n = +n) || n < 0 || !idBase.length) return null; 
  const numRe = new RegExp(idBase + '(\\d+)', 'i'); 
  const els = []; 
  for (let el of document.querySelectorAll(`[id^="${idBase}"]`)) {
    let num = +((el.id.match(numRe) || [0, infinity])[1]); 
    if (!isFinite(num)) continue; 
    if (!withN && (num === n)) continue; 
    els.push({ el, num }); 
  }
  els.sort((a, b) => Math.abs(n - a.num) - Math.abs(n - b.num)); 
  return els.map(o => o.el); 
} 


// ------------------- test -------------------
for (let i = 1; i <= 150; i++)
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<div id="block${i}">${i}</div>`); 
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', e => {
  for (let el of document.querySelectorAll('[id^="block"]'))
    el.style.background = '#fff'; 
  const els = findByNum('block', Math.abs(e.target.value), false), 
        cnt = els.length, 
        stp = 50 / cnt * 4; 
  for (let i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
    els[i].style.background = `hsl(200deg, 100%, ${50 + i * stp}%)`; 
});
```

```css
label { display: block; margin: 1rem 0.25rem; }

div {
  display: inline-block; width: 3em; 
  margin: 0 1px 0 0; padding: 0.3rem 0rem; 
  text-align: center; font: 0.7rem/1.8 monospace; 
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #ccc; }
```

```html
<label>Число в id: <input type="number"></label>
```

Два ближайших по id элемента, по одному "слева" и "справа" от `n` (индексы 0 и 1 соотв.):

```
findByNum('block', n, false).slice(0, 2)
```